# How can I prove that the following set is not a manifold

Tags: calculus

> Consider  $(C,o) =  \left\{ \left(x,y\right)\thinspace|\thinspace x\cdot y=0\right\} \subset\left(\mathbb{R}^{2},o\right)$
> (Where $(\mathbb{R}^2,o)$ is a notation for the germ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ at the origin.
> Prove that $(C,o)$ is not a germ of a $C^0$ manifold.

I am allowed to use the following equivalent:

$ (M,o) \subset (\mathbb{R}^N,o)$ is a germ of an $n$ dimensional manifold $\iff $  there exists $ \left(\mathbb{R}^{n},0\right)\overset{\varphi}{\longrightarrow}\left(M,0\right)\subset\left(\mathbb{R}^{N},0\right) $ such that $ \text{rank}\left[\varphi'|_{0}\right]=n $,

$\iff $

$(M,0) $ can be described by equations $ f_{1}\left(\underline{x}\right)=0=....=f_{N-n}\left(\underline{x}\right) $

Where the rank of $ \underset{\left(N-n\right)\times N}{\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\nabla f_{1}\\
\vdots\\
\nabla f_{N-n}
\end{pmatrix}}} $ is full ($N-n$)

$\iff$

There exists a diffeomorphism, $\varphi$ of $(\mathbb{R}^N,o)$ such that $$ \varphi\left(M,0\right)=\left(\mathbb{R}^{n},0\right)\times\left\{ 0\right\} \subset\left(\mathbb{R}^{n},0\right)\times\left(\mathbb{R}^{N-n},0\right) $$

Im not sure how to prove it in a formal way using one of this conditions.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any informal ideas, perhaps about how the geometric or topological structure at the origin differs from an open interval?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, my informal idea is to assume that the set is diffeomorphic to $ R$ locally at the origin, but if we remove the origin from the set I mentioned we get 4 connected parts, while removing the origin at $R$ will only result in 2 connected parts. Problem is I did not prove that diffeomorphism preserve connectness (and why would of course did not proved that it preserved connectness after removing a point)

Comment: You're essentially there: A continuous image of a connected set is connected, and a diffeomorphism is, in particular, continuous with continuous inverse. Further, the image under a bijection of a set with one point removed is the image of the set with the image of that point removed.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwan Thanks. In the idea I mention I assumed that if the set is indeed a manifold, than it is 1 dimensional manifold (and therefore diffeomorphic locally to $\mathbb{R}$. Is there a loss of geberality here? (Formally, shoukd I assume that it is an $n$ dimensional manifold for some $n$ ?)

Comment: At each point other than the origin, $(C, o)$ is locally diffeomorphic to the reals, and dimension of a manifold is constant on connected components. That said, it's unnecessary if you show no Cartesian space has the property that removing a point from a ball leaves a set with four path components.